# How to restrict public access to a webapplication?

Tags: java, spring, public, restrict

I have created a web application with Spring framework in which users can login/register and other. The client wants to upload the application to a hosting provider so that he can access it.

The problem is that the client doesn't want to be public. He wants to access the URL, prompts him for an user and a password and after that to be able create accounts to the application, login and other stuff.

Any idea how to restrict public access to the application without changing the existing Spring Security authentication mechanism?

Comment: Do you know the clients IP address? If so you could put a filter on your server to only allow access from that address.

Comment: No. I don't know the clients IP. Thanks.

Comment: even after repeated reading-attempts i fail to find any question in these sentences ... what do you want to achieve? It looks like you want to use authentication. Thats what spring security can do. Nothing to "change" here.

Comment: As @specializt pointed out the application is already protected by username based authentication. You can add SSL mutual auth for an extra layer of security (if the hosting server supports that) but it will come with the hassle of managing the client certifcates.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some additional authorization. For nginx there is http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html where you specify login and password to whole site and then proxy pass it to your spring server.

Comment: Adding another, nigh-identical auth mechanism serves no purpose whatsoever - some people call it "snake oil".

Comment: If he already use some proxy to access spring webservice it is easy to do some "global authorization". It can be simple and non connected to service accounts.

Comment: it doesnt matter how cheap the snake oil is - it still is snake oil.

Comment: Hosting providers does not allow to install such applications! Thanks @kTT

Comment: .... entirely wrong. You can order authentication with quite a few hosting providers - some require you to create the configfiles yourself and some offer UIs for purposes like these, this is not 1990 anymore.